# Playing a .wav file when the count is finished

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, applet

I've made a countdown clock that works, but I want it to play a sound the countdown is finished. My problem is that I get a NullPointerException and I don't know how to solve it. Here's the code without the imports:

```
public class ReminderBeep {
Toolkit toolkit;

private String Path_to_sound = "sirenpolice5.wav";
public AudioClip audioclip;

Timer timer;

public ReminderBeep(int seconds) {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Time's up!");
        try {
             URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(Path_to_sound);
             AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);

             Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
             clip.open(audioIn);
             clip.start();
            } catch (MalformedURLException murle) {
            System.out.println(murle);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.exit(0); 
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to countdown clock. Please type how many seconds you wanna count down from");
    int sec = scan.nextInt();
    new ReminderBeep(sec);
    System.out.println("Counting");
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is the null pointer happening? I'm guessing the url variable. You should post the stack trace.

Comment: @MathieuFortin Have fixed the problem but it doesn't play a sound. The program runs normally but it doesn't play the sound file

Answer (score 0):

Have found the problem I was missing a `Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);`